# Getting 400 - Bad Request Java Client

Tags: java, http, request, httpclient, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to do a request using a small Java program but I'm getting a 400 - Bad Request as response:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https")
                .setHost("somehost.com")
                .setPath("/API/v1/export").build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
        post.setHeader("X-API-ID", "myId");
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "csv"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", "userId"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        JsonNode responseJson = sendResponseEngineRequest(post);
```

This **responseJson** returns the following value:

> {"meta":{"httpStatus":"400 - Bad
>   Request","error":{"errorMessage":"Invalid Content-Type.
>   expected=application/json
>   found=application/x-www-form-urlencoded","errorCode":"RP_0.1"}}}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is literally in the error you're getting.

You specify you will only accept  `post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` and the error is telling you that what you're requesting is  `found=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

If you have control over the endpoint you're requesting data, change it to application/json.  If you don't change `post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` to `post.setHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can request "application/json" and as well how I'm requesting "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" thats not clear for me.

Comment: Do you have control of the host you're requesting data from?

Comment: Well not really, is a host from a provider.

Comment: Then the content type that the URL returns cannot be changed.  This means when you request it, you will not be able to get application/json data from it because that's not what it returns.  The error message is saying what it's returning 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.  You could probably clear up your error by changing application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded in your code.

Comment: Well already tried that, but I'n still getting:

{"meta":{"httpStatus":"400 - Bad Request","error":{"errorMessage":"Invalid Content-Type. expected=application/json found=application/x-www-form-urlencoded","errorCode":"RP_0.1"}}}

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a POST request, you may need to provide both `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers.

`Accept:` What you are expecting to receive.
`Content-Type:` What you are sending to server

```
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my program i am also got this error and found that the link not accepting repeated values.

so please check your link It may not accept any repeated parameters which is already available in that link.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As there are additional answers, please explain yours a little bit and the Pros of yours.